# How to change the way eclipse formats my code to a more cleaner format.(Beautify or clean up my code :java)

Tags: java, code-formatting

My eclipse is formatting code like shown below and causing my code to be long having more lines of code eventhough it is not.

```
  // Inserting Person record
if (personDTO.getInsertPerson() != null
        && personDTO
                .getInsertPerson()) {
    newPersonID = super
            .getPersonDBM()
            .insertHRPerson(
                    personDTO);
    //inserting into ADS_Person_Logs                                    
    personLogsDTO = super
            .getPersonDBM()
            .getPerson(newPersonID);
    personLogsDTO
            .setAction(PERSON_INSERT);
    super.getPersonDBM()
            .insertHRPersonLogs(
                    personLogsDTO);

    if (logDTO.getGyr().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        for (BigDecimal tempRegId : transactionLogMap
                .keySet()) {
            writeHRFeedTransactionLogEntry(personDTO,SUCCESS_MSG + 
                                    transactionLogMap
                                    .get(tempRegId).getMessage(),                                                                                
                                    transactionLogMap.get(tempRegId)
                                    .getGyr(),
                                    transactionLogRegionMap
                                    .get(tempRegId),
                                    newPersonID,tempRegId);
        }
        insertedRecordsWithWarn++;
    } else {
        for (BigDecimal tempRegId : transactionLogMap
                .keySet()) {
            writeHRFeedTransactionLogEntry(personDTO,SUCCESS_MSG+ transactionLogMap
                                    .get(tempRegId).getMessage(),
                                    transactionLogMap
                                    .get(tempRegId).getGyr(),
                                    transactionLogRegionMap
                                    .get(tempRegId),
                                    newPersonID,tempRegId);
        }
        insertedRecords++;
    }
}
```

But i want code to be displayed like belwo when i presss ctrl + shift + F.

```
// Inserting Person record
if (personDTO.getInsertPerson() != null
        && personDTO.getInsertPerson()) {
    newPersonID = super.getPersonDBM().insertHRPerson(personDTO);
    //inserting into ADS_Person_Logs                                    
    personLogsDTO = super.getPersonDBM().getPerson(newPersonID);
    personLogsDTO.setAction(PERSON_INSERT);
    super.getPersonDBM().insertHRPersonLogs(personLogsDTO);

    if (logDTO.getGyr()    .equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        for (BigDecimal tempRegId : transactionLogMap.keySet()) {
            writeHRFeedTransactionLogEntry(personDTO,SUCCESS_MSG + 
                                    transactionLogMap.get(tempRegId).getMessage(),                                                                                
                                    transactionLogMap.get(tempRegId).getGyr(),
                                    transactionLogRegionMap.get(tempRegId),
                                    newPersonID,tempRegId);
        }
        insertedRecordsWithWarn++;
    } else {
        for (BigDecimal tempRegId : transactionLogMap
                .keySet()) {
            writeHRFeedTransactionLogEntry(personDTO,SUCCESS_MSG+
                                    transactionLogMap.get(tempRegId).getMessage(),
                                    transactionLogMap.get(tempRegId).getGyr(),
                                    transactionLogRegionMap.get(tempRegId),
                                    newPersonID,tempRegId);
        }
        insertedRecords++;
    }
}
```

Even if its not in the exact format...i just need to reduce te number of lines of code since it is making my code look shabby.

Please provide suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using below xml for formating. This may help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profiles version="11">
<profile kind="CodeFormatterProfile" name="korada [built-in]" version="11">
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_if" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_colon_in_assert" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_enum_constant" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_semicolon" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.align_type_members_on_columns" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_colon_in_case" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.format_line_comments" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.number_of_empty_lines_to_preserve" value="1"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_between_brackets_in_array_type_reference" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_switch" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_between_type_declarations" value="1"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_parenthesized_expression_in_return" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_in_empty_method_body" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_annotation_type_declaration" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_statements_compare_to_body" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_after_opening_brace_in_array_initializer" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.format_guardian_clause_on_one_line" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.insert_new_line_before_root_tags" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_colon_in_for" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.size" value="4"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_angle_bracket_in_type_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_before_imports" value="1"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_colon_in_case" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_enum_constant_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_before_new_chunk" value="1"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.continuation_indentation" value="2"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_binary_operator" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_constructor_declaration_parameters" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_for" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_superinterfaces" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_parameters_in_method_declaration" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_assignment" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_before_member_type" value="1"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_constructor_declaration_throws" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_conditional_expression" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_while" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.indent_parameter_description" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.format_html" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_allocation_expression" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_method_declaration_throws" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_enum_constant" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.format_source_code" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_enum_declarations" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_angle_bracket_in_parameterized_type_reference" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_annotation" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_between_empty_parens_in_method_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_colon_in_conditional" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_unary_operator" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_question_in_conditional" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_in_empty_annotation_declaration" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indentation.size" value="4"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_multiple_local_declarations" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_postfix_operator" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_superinterfaces_in_enum_declaration" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_enum_constant_arguments" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_semicolon_in_for" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_constructor_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_at_in_annotation_type_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_explicitconstructorcall_arguments" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_anonymous_type_declaration" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.lineSplit" value="250"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_type_declaration" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_block" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_in_empty_type_declaration" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_method_invocation_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_while" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_enum_constant" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.clear_blank_lines_in_block_comment" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_at_in_annotation_type_declaration" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_in_empty_enum_constant" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_angle_bracket_in_type_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_angle_bracket_in_type_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_before_closing_brace_in_array_initializer" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_array_initializer" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_superclass_in_type_declaration" value="16"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_cast" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_in_empty_enum_declaration" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_synchronized" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.format_header" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_colon_in_for" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_at_in_annotation" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_before_else_in_if_statement" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_arguments_in_explicit_constructor_call" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_method_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_allocation_expression" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_multiple_fields" value="16"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_at_end_of_file_if_missing" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_explicitconstructorcall_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_in_empty_block" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_closing_paren_in_cast" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_before_finally_in_try_statement" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.keep_then_statement_on_same_line" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_binary_operator" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_body_declarations_compare_to_annotation_declaration_header" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_constructor_declaration" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_method_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_expressions_in_array_initializer" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_method_declaration_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_method_declaration" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_enum_constant" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_between_empty_parens_in_annotation_type_member_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_angle_bracket_in_type_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_angle_bracket_in_parameterized_type_reference" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_annotation_type_member_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_before_field" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_throws_clause_in_method_declaration" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_method_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_constructor_declaration_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_type_parameters" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_switch" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.format_javadoc_comments" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_bracket_in_array_allocation_expression" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_annotation" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.format_block_comments" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_array_initializer" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_in_empty_anonymous_type_declaration" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_binary_expression" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_between_empty_braces_in_array_initializer" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.wrap_before_binary_operator" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_after_package" value="1"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_catch" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_superinterfaces_in_type_declaration" value="16"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_colon_in_labeled_statement" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_semicolon_in_for" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_and_in_type_parameter" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_catch" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_before_while_in_do_statement" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_between_import_groups" value="1"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_method_declaration_throws" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_prefix_operator" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_ellipsis" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_constructor_declaration" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_question_in_wildcard" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.clear_blank_lines_in_javadoc_comment" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_arguments_in_allocation_expression" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_type_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_after_imports" value="1"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_colon_in_conditional" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_enum_declaration" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_parameterized_type_reference" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_before_catch_in_try_statement" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier" value="error"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_arguments_in_enum_constant" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_block_in_case" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_enum_declaration" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_for_increments" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_for" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_before_first_class_body_declaration" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.keep_else_statement_on_same_line" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_empty_lines" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.insert_new_line_for_parameter" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_parenthesized_expression_in_throw" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_while" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_closing_brace_in_block" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source" value="1.5"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_for_increments" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_body_declarations_compare_to_enum_declaration_header" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_between_empty_parens_in_constructor_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.line_length" value="80"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_prefix_operator" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_type_declaration" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_assignment_operator" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance" value="1.5"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_method_invocation" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_angle_bracket_in_type_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.compact_else_if" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_bracket_in_array_reference" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_enum_declarations" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_question_in_conditional" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_angle_bracket_in_type_parameters" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_method_invocation" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.use_tabs_only_for_leading_indentations" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_type_arguments" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_switch" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_parameters_in_constructor_declaration" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_between_empty_brackets_in_array_allocation_expression" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_for" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_constructor_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_synchronized" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.number_of_blank_lines_at_beginning_of_method_body" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_annotation" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_angle_bracket_in_parameterized_type_reference" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_switchstatements_compare_to_switch" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_constructor_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_annotation" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_if" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_colon_in_default" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier" value="error"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_annotation" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_between_empty_parens_in_enum_constant" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_bracket_in_array_reference" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_bracket_in_array_type_reference" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_array_initializer" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_catch" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_synchronized" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.keep_empty_array_initializer_on_one_line" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform" value="1.5"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_bracket_in_array_reference" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_switch" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_brace_in_array_initializer" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_compact_if" value="16"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_question_in_wildcard" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_colon_in_assert" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_method_declaration" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_ellipsis" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_arguments_in_qualified_allocation_expression" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_statements_compare_to_block" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_parenthesized_expression" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_body_declarations_compare_to_type_header" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_closing_angle_bracket_in_type_parameters" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_type_arguments" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.keep_imple_if_on_one_line" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_between_empty_parens_in_method_invocation" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_multiple_local_declarations" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_annotation_type_declaration" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_selector_in_method_invocation" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_body_declarations_compare_to_enum_constant_header" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_switch" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_assignment_operator" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.never_indent_line_comments_on_first_column" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_unary_operator" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_if" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_colon_in_labeled_statement" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_bracket_in_array_allocation_expression" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_switchstatements_compare_to_cases" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.continuation_indentation_for_array_initializer" value="2"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.indent_root_tags" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_enum_constants" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_parameterized_type_reference" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_parenthesized_expression" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_constructor_declaration_throws" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_throws_clause_in_constructor_declaration" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_arguments_in_method_invocation" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.char" value="tab"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_before_package" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_method_invocation_arguments" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_breaks_compare_to_cases" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_for_inits" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_multiple_field_declarations" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_superinterfaces" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.put_empty_statement_on_new_line" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_method_declaration_parameters" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_before_method" value="1"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_multiple_field_declarations" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_for_inits" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_anonymous_type_declaration" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_after_annotation" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_cast" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_closing_angle_bracket_in_type_arguments" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.never_indent_block_comments_on_first_column" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_comma_in_array_initializer" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_parenthesized_expression" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_paren_in_enum_constant" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_paren_in_method_invocation" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_postfix_operator" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_block" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_brace_in_array_initializer" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_closing_bracket_in_array_allocation_expression" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_and_in_type_parameter" value="insert"/>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Save this code in an xml file.
In eclipse,
Windows->Preferences->Java-->Code Formatter--> Import, this xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try changing settings in "Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit"? Especially the settings in "new Lines" and "Line Wrapping" tabs.

Also if you like, you could find the same setting dialog in projects settings which will affect your current project only.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the maximum line length used by Eclipse in the Preferences menu :

```
Window -> Preferences - Java -> Code Style -> Formatter
```

Create a custom formatter, edit it, go to the `Line Wrapping` tab and increase the first value. You can change pretty much anything you want about the auto-formatter.

As pointed by adou, you can also edit project-based preferences and define a project specific formatter.